# Qt - pyside - saveGeometry() saveState()

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qsettings

I have a Qt program and currently I use the Qsettings.saveGeometry() and Qsettings.saveState() functions to allow the program to restore the layout that the user set in the previous session. However not all geometry is saved, only the main window and not the children especially floating position of docked windows and table column widths within docked windows.

This thread seems to attempt to provide an answer (but in C++ and not python): http://www.qtforum.org/article/38362/save-geometry-of-all-widgets-recursively.html

I am coding in Python and my C++ is not very good so I can't fully follow the example at the above link.

Does anyone know if that approach works?

In general is it possible to use Qsettings to store floating position of docked windows and table column widths?

Could anyone suggest a python/pyside based solution?

Many thanks.

Ron

Comment: The link you provide does not implement a solution. It simply prints out the geometry of every child widget. They were suggesting this be used to work out which widgets needed saving. In short, that code iterates over all children of the main window (`my_window.children()`) and checks if the child inherits from `QWidget` (`my_child_widget.isWidgetType()`). You could do something similar and call `my_child_widget.saveGeometry()` for every child you care about. You may need to recursively check the children of each child too using this method.

Comment: It might thus be easier for you to just keep a list of references to every widget you are going to want to save, and iterate over that list calling `saveGeometry` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys. Here is the answer. There is a bug in Qt. When the main window is maximised and the QdocWidget's are docked (not floating) then the floating position is not saved.

This code is a simple workaround.

to save:

```
settings = QtCore.QSettings(org_name, app_name)
is_floating = main_win._ui.dockWin.isFloating()
settings.setValue('dockWin/isFloating', is_floating)
main_win._ui.dockWin.setFloating(True)
settings.setValue('geometry', main_win.saveGeometry())
settings.setValue('state', main_win.saveState())
```

to restore:

```
settings = QtCore.QSettings(org_name, app_name)
main_win.restoreGeometry(settings.value('geometry'))
main_win.restoreState(settings.value('state'))
main_win._ui.dockWin.setFloating(settings.value('dockWin/isFloating')=='true')
```

Answer (score 1):

> This thread seems to attempt to provide an answer (but in C++ and not python): http://www.qtforum.org/article/38362/save-geometry-of-all-widgets-recursively.html

As three_pineapples pointed out, iterating over all widgets is not a good idea since things you wouldn't want to save, (buttons, label) are also derived from `QWidget`.

I'd suggest to simply give meaningful name to each floating docked-window:

```
floatingWindow.setObjectName("floatingWindow")
```

Then you can iterate against object names instead seeking widgets from child object. To create a `QSettings` group for that particular window:

```
QSettings settings
# Write geometry
settings.setValue("floatingWindow/size", floatingWindow.size())
settings.setValue("floatingWindow/pos", floatingWindow.pos())
# Read geometry
floatingWindow.setSize(settings.value("floatingWindow/size").toSize())
floatingWindow.setPos(settings.value("floatingWindow/pos").toPos())
```

You can make this easier by using common pattern for names, e.g. `floatingMain`, `floatingTools`, `floatingMenu`.

Comment: Thanks v.much will try this and report back on outcome.

Comment: @ Leben. Thanks for this suggestion but as far as I can see QDockWidget has no .setSize(). Nevertheless, I have made some progress. I have updated my question above. I would be grateful if you could have another look.

Comment: Actually none of these approaches seem to work. I have asked a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975913/qt-pyside-savegeom-savestate-again